# java - Change classloader for a given class

Tags: java, classpath

So all the resource reading in this project is done like so:

```
SomeLoadingClass.class.getResource(resource);
```

For a test, I'd like to hook up a different config file for use. Just as a safety net that the config file has the right stuff in it.

Given that I'm writing a test in test `class A`, and the above code snippet happens somewhere else, how can I - Add a new file to the classpath (presumably for the class `SomeLoadingClass`) so that the config file I want is used, not the one that is set in the `.classpath` file.

I'd prefer to be able to "overwrite" the existing config file, instead of blowing away the entire contents of the `.classpath` - is that possible? If so, how?

Apologies - I've read a few of the classpath entries here but they don't seem to do quite what I want. (They're all about overwriting the current thread's classloader, which doesn't seem appropriate here - i.e. does not work)

EDIT for this *one* test i would like to shimmy with the classpath. That's it, nothing more. I don't want to change every other test. Also, no maven is being used.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven, i believe you could put your test config file in the src/test/resources dir with the same name and it will override the real config file at test time.